# Are G and H necessarily isomorphic?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Let $G$ and $H$ be two simple graphs, both of them with seven vertices, each of which is of degree 2. Are G and H necessarily isomorphic?

The graphs $G$ and $H$ must have a cycle since each vertex is of degree 2 and therefore they are isomorphic.In general, this should be true for a graph with $n$ vertices with the above property? Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; one of them could be $C_7$ (the $7$-vertex cycle) and the other could be the disjoint union of $C_3$ and $C_4$.

If you additionally knew that the graphs were connected, then there would be only one possibility.

Comment: You're right, it didn't say connected...should pay attention to definition. But if they were then the answer is correct right?

Comment: Yes, if they were connected, then they would both have to be $C_7$. (And in the general $n$-vertex case, $C_n$ is the only connected $2$-regular graph.)